# How to not fail on wait.until (expected condition)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I have a table which might or might not display based on the URL. Now my test loops through all the given URLS. I have to click on a search button after which I validate the table existence.
My table was failing initially even though table was clearly visible. I added following code to handle that problem:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(data.Driver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("abc")));
Boolean tableVisibility = data.Driver.findElements(By.id("12345abcd")).size() > 0;
if (tableVisibility == true) {
    result.logInfo("table displaying successfully");
}
Boolean isElmPresent =  data.Driver.findElements(By.id("labelMessage")).size() > 0;
if (isPresent == true) {
    this.updateDBTbl(abc,xyz);
}
```

This statement helped me solve the issue with table load. But now I am running into an issue when table can't be found. Actually, when table is not found, we get a new label that mentions "we need to contact system desk" which I need to report in my database. But in case of wait.until statement, when it doesn't see the table after 30 seconds, it errors out and stops the execution. because of this, label never gets validated. I have commented out the *wait.until statement* for now and instead added Thread.Sleep which resolved that issue but I am not a fan of hard wait at all. So I am wondering if there is a better way to handle this problem.

Comment: catch the exception and set tableVisibility to false.

Comment: you could also do something like this:   webelements = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.id("12345abcd")));  then check for size... try/catch the whole thing.  and/or maybe create another bool for "tableNotFoundInTime"?  Which might make the devs speed up things.

Comment: Please clarify your code... add some comments to indicate what each locator is looking for. For example, what is `By.id("abc")` finding? Is that the table? What is `By.id("12345abcd")` finding? Is that table rows? The last one I'm assuming is the label to contact system desk?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try{
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("abc")));
 Boolean tableVisibility = data.Driver.findElements(By.id("12345abcd")).size() > 0;
                if (tableVisibility==true) {
                    result.logInfo("table displaying successfully");
                }
Boolean isElmPresent=  data.Driver.findElements(By.id("labelMessage")).size() > 0;
                if (isPresent == true) {
                    this.updateDBTbl(abc,xyz);
                }
}catch(ElementNotVisibleException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: I think it'll throw timeout... maybe just catch "Exception" instead?... findElements won't throw.

Comment: The question states that he is trying to deal with the situation where the table is missing and instead it finds the message. If the table is not found with your code, the message is not gathered and stored.

Comment: I think "ElementNotVisibleException" is thrown only when the element exists but it has a width/height of 0...  if it times out it won't be caught... but still seems like you'd need to check for the label in the catch... at least if I'm understanding the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic flow needs to be adjusted slightly. You need to:

1. Wait for the table to be present

   1. If present, log success
   2. If not present, log failure and log label message

```
// not sure what this does
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("abc")));

// is table present?
try
{
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("12345abcd")));
    result.logInfo("table displaying successfully");
}
catch (TimeoutException e)
{
    // table is not present
    result.logInfo("table NOT displaying successfully");

    // report contact system desk message
    if (data.Driver.findElements(By.id("labelMessage")).size() > 0)
    {
        this.updateDBTbl(abc,xyz);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here are the solutions you can try:
1. check if element is visible or not-if it is visible perform your actions on it, if not - then perform actions on the other element that should display if table is absent
2. add ignore exception to your wait
3. wrap in try/catch block to handle absence of table